Using ORM peewee, a part of my query is lost when converting it to a CTE
Using peewee, the syntax of unpacking a JSON_TABLE is lost from a CTE when I try to use it in my main query.
With the ORM peewee I create a CTE that uses the JSON_TABLE function to unpack the JSON table contained in a field, then inserting a record for each element in the JSON object in the output table, duplicating other columns. I join this table of unpacked JSON objects to another table on the field 'object_id'. Ultimately, I want to unpack and join multiple tables of that kind on their common field 'object_id'. To do so, I transform the above query to a CTE. All this is done a function call which returns the CTE.
Overall, I want flexibility for compiling SQL queries for combinations field_id which resemble the following properly executing query:
WITH solution AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ost_form_entry.object_id as ost_form_entry_object_id,
        jt.my_key,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(ost_form_entry_values.value, CONCAT('$.', jt.my_key))) AS my_value,
        ost_ticket.number,
        ost_ticket.ticket_id,
        ost_ticket.created AS created_date,
        ost_ticket.closed AS closed_date
    FROM
        ost_form_entry_values
        JOIN ost_form_entry ON ost_form_entry_values.entry_id = ost_form_entry.id
        JOIN ost_ticket ON ost_form_entry.object_id = ost_ticket.ticket_id,
        JSON_TABLE(
            JSON_KEYS(ost_form_entry_values.value),
            '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                my_key VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
            )
        ) AS jt
    WHERE
        JSON_VALID(ost_form_entry_values.value)
        AND JSON_TYPE(ost_form_entry_values.value) = 'OBJECT'
        AND ost_form_entry_values.field_id = 67
),
user_type AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        jt.my_key,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(ost_form_entry_values.value, CONCAT('$.', jt.my_key))) AS my_value,
        ost_form_entry.object_id as ost_form_entry_object_id
    FROM
        ost_form_entry_values
        JOIN ost_form_entry ON ost_form_entry_values.entry_id = ost_form_entry.id,
        JSON_TABLE(
            JSON_KEYS(ost_form_entry_values.value),
            '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                my_key VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
            )
        ) AS jt
    WHERE
        JSON_VALID(ost_form_entry_values.value)
        AND JSON_TYPE(ost_form_entry_values.value) = 'OBJECT'
        AND ost_form_entry_values.field_id = 76
),
response AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CONVERT(ost_form_entry_values.value, DATETIME) AS my_value,
        ost_form_entry.object_id as ost_form_entry_object_id
    FROM
        ost_form_entry_values
        JOIN ost_form_entry ON ost_form_entry_values.entry_id = ost_form_entry.id
    WHERE
        ost_form_entry_values.value IS NOT NULL
        AND ost_form_entry_values.field_id = 75
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    solution.number AS ticket_no,
    solution.created_date,
    solution.closed_date,
    response.my_value AS first_response_date,
    solution.my_value AS solution,
    user_type.my_value AS user_type,
    solution.ticket_id
FROM
    solution
    JOIN user_type ON solution.ost_form_entry_object_id = user_type.ost_form_entry_object_id
    JOIN response ON solution.ost_form_entry_object_id = response.ost_form_entry_object_id
WHERE
    solution.closed_date BETWEEN '2024-05-22' AND '2024-08-26'
;

However, when I attempt to compile my main query using the CTEs returned by my function the logic of unpacking the JSON_TABLE is lost.
Here is the CTE that unpacks the JSON table, as formulated in peewee:
cte = (OstFormEntryValues
                    .select(
                    OstFormEntryValues.entry_id,
                    OstFormEntryValues.field_id,
                    SQL('jt.my_key').alias(f'{field_name}_key'),
                    fn.JSON_UNQUOTE(fn.JSON_EXTRACT(OstFormEntryValues.value, fn.CONCAT('$.', SQL('jt.my_key')))).alias(field_name)
                )
                .from_(OstFormEntryValues, SQL('JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(value), \'$[*]\' COLUMNS (my_key VARCHAR(100) PATH \'$\'))').alias('jt'))
                .where(
                    fn.JSON_VALID(OstFormEntryValues.value) &
                    (fn.JSON_TYPE(OstFormEntryValues.value) == 'OBJECT') &
                    (OstFormEntryValues.field_id == field_id)
                )
                .cte(field_name))

I join this CTE to another table creating a query:
query = (OstFormEntry
           .select(
               OstFormEntry.object_id,
               cte.c.entry_id,
               cte.c.field_id,
               cte.c[field_name]
           )
           .join(cte, on=(OstFormEntry.id == cte.c.entry_id))
           .with_cte(cte)
          )

This query produces the desired result, the following SQL query which produces the correct output:
WITH `solution_found` AS (
SELECT
    `t1`.`entry_id`,
    `t1`.`field_id`,
    jt.my_key AS `solution_found_key`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`t1`.`value`,
    CONCAT(%s,
    jt.my_key))) AS `solution_found`
FROM
    `ost_form_entry_values` AS `t1`,
    JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(value),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (my_key VARCHAR(100) PATH '$')) AS `jt`
WHERE
    ((JSON_VALID(`t1`.`value`)
        AND (JSON_TYPE(`t1`.`value`) = %s))
        AND (`t1`.`field_id` = %s)))
SELECT
    `t2`.`object_id`,
    `solution_found`.`entry_id`,
    `solution_found`.`field_id`,
    `solution_found`.`solution_found`
FROM
    `ost_form_entry` AS `t2`
INNER JOIN `solution_found` ON
    (`t2`.`id` = `solution_found`.`entry_id`),
    ['$.', 'OBJECT', 67]

Then I wrap the above query as a CTE and use it to build my main query, joining it to another table:
json_cte = query.cte('json_unpacked')


query = (OstTicket
                 .select(
                        OstTicket.number,
                        OstTicket.ticket_id,
                        json_cte.c.entry_id,
                        json_cte.c.field_id,
                        json_cte.c.solution_found,
                    )
                    .join(json_cte, on=(OstTicket.ticket_id == json_cte.c.object_id))
                    .with_cte(json_cte)
                )

The resulting SQL query does no longer contains the commands to unpack the JSON table, and the WHERE statement is also no longer reproduced:
WITH `solution_found` AS (
SELECT
    `t1`.`object_id`,
    `solution_found`.`entry_id`,
    `solution_found`.`field_id`,
    `solution_found`.`solution_found`
FROM
    `ost_form_entry` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `solution_found` ON
    (`t1`.`id` = `solution_found`.`entry_id`))
SELECT
    `t2`.`number`,
    `t2`.`ticket_id`,
    `solution_found`.`entry_id`,
    `solution_found`.`field_id`,
    `solution_found`.`solution_found`
FROM
    `ost_ticket` AS `t2`
INNER JOIN `solution_found` ON
    (`t2`.`ticket_id` = `solution_found`.`object_id`)',
    []

PeeWee does support using SOME of the JSON functions via the Playhouse extension which my initial queries uses. However, the JSON_TABLE function is not implemented. Hence, the call to JSON_TABLE and JSON_KEYS are inserted as raw SQL. Is this related to the failure of inserting the correct syntax in my final query?
How can I force peewee to "remember" the full syntax of my CTEs, including the raw SQL?
Is there another approach to solving my problem of unpacking the JSON objects before joining the result of that to other tables?

This may be a bug in Peewee, just FYI. I'm taking a look.

It looks like this would produce some kind of a "nested" CTE, if I understand correctly? Nested CTEs are not supported. I suggest decomposing it so that there is only a single layer or CTE's.
Please share the full SQL you are trying to achieve (and which runs properly in mariadb) and I'd be happy to give it a try to making it work.

Thank you @coleifer, for your quick response.
I added an example of a properly running mariaDB query of the kind that I want to compile with peewee. Hopefully that helps to clarify if there is a solution, bug or no support.
A possibility of a workaround would be to extract from the db for each field_id and then join the tables in pandas, but it wouldn't it be more elegant to let peewee & SQL do that job!

Man this thing is so crazy I don't know if it's even worth trying.

Haha, which part is so crazy @coleifer?
I understand that what I am trying to build is a "nested" CTE and would appreciate your comment on whether you think this is possible with peewee or not. Maybe we could implement it?
